# Using imshow() on a Basemap map

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to project a 2D array on a Basemap object in Python3.5.
The approach that I sued was to create a simple Basemap object with cylindrical project, such that there is no need to map the lat/lon coordinates, and then use imshow() on the same axis to plot my date. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work, since I see absolutely nothing.

The same exact procedure works fine when I try to plot a line. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here a sample of the code I am using:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
    import numpy as np

    # Draw map with cyl projection
    m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=-140, llcrnrlat=20, urcrnrlon=-70, urcrnrlat=70,
                resolution='l')
    m.drawcountries(linewidth=1.8)
    m.drawstates(linewidth=1.2)
    m.drawcoastlines(1.8)
    m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#99ffff')
    m.fillcontinents(color='#cc9966', lake_color='#99ffff', alpha=0.5)

    ax = plt.gca()

    # Plot line from lat/lon: (36, -113) to (40, -100)
    ax.plot([-113, -100], [36, 40], linewidth=4)

    # Use imshow()
    extent = [-113, -100, 36, 40]
    imag = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
    im = ax.imshow(imag, extent=extent, cmap='hot_r')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

The image will be there, but hidden behind the land shape.

You can use the `zorder` to bring it in front, e.g.

```
ax.imshow(..., zorder=3)
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!